# Client-side model filtering with Derby.js

Tags: javascript, client-side, derbyjs

I am creating a webpage that will display some models as a table and allow the user to filter the items of that model by tags.

I am new to Derby.js and currently have it working to the point where I am able to send the data from the server to the client with `model.set('items', items);`

and in the view

```
{#each :items}
    {.title} - {.description}
{/}
```

All the items also have a `tags` property. I'd like give the user a list of these tags and allow hi to filter the displayed items by clicking on the tags he's interested in. How do I go about this?

As I understand it, I probably have to do my templating client-side instead of the current way - if so, how do I access the model object in client-side JS in Derby.js

Alternatively, is there a way to dynamically specify the filters to the model in Derby.js?

Answer (score 0):

```
model.filter('items').ref('_page.items');

{#each _page.items}
  {.title} - {.description}
{/}
```